# Is there a Google Sheets functions equivalent of mysql_fetch_row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

Is there any way to get the row result in Google just like mysql_fetch_row that returns only the row base on query statement?

I hope there has a formula for this.

Using this formula `=Query(IMPORTRANGE("",""),"Select Col1 where Col1='somevalue')` i want to get only the counts of row results instead of displaying the data on my sheet.

Comment: Using this formula =Query(IMPORTRANGE("",""),"Select Col1 where Col1='somevalue') i want to get only the counts of row results instead of displaying the data on my sheet.

Comment: add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Using this formula `=Query(IMPORTRANGE("",""),"Select Col1 where Col1='somevalue')` i want to get only the counts of row results instead of displaying the data on my sheet.

Use `=Query(IMPORTRANGE("",""),"Select Count(Col1) where Col1='somevalue' label Count(Col1) ''")`